# Laravel mailbox inbound parse sendgrid

Tags: laravel, email, sendgrid, inbound

So I'm trying to make my own inbox for emails using the followin packag [beyondcode/laravel-mailbox](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-mailbox/1.0/getting-started/installation.html)

I installed the package on a blank project, in order to test it out.

I can send emails with the sendgrid API, so that's not a problem at all.

Now, I have some environment variables set;

```
MAILBOX_DRIVER=sendgrid
MAILBOX_HTTP_USERNAME=laravel-mailbox
MAILBOX_HTTP_PASSWORD=secret
```

The config just the same as given in the package.

In my `AppServiceProvider`, I have in the `boot` the following:

```
Mailbox::catchAll(static function(InboundEmail $email) {
    // Handle the incoming email
    Log::info('#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#');
    Log::info($email);
    Log::info('#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#');
});
```

But when I take a look in the logs, when I send an email to `whatever@rallypodium.be`, nothing hapens...

This is my DNS configuration:

[image: DNS]

And here is the inbound parse config on the sendgrid side:

[image: Sendgrid config]

What am I missing or doing wrong here? I looked at my access logs and not even a request is being made to the server from sendgrid...

So How can I make sure I can receive messages to `whatever@mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS should also have a few CNAME records so that you can verify your domain with SendGrid.